# How can I use the parent's sibling bucket path in bucket_script?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I want to use the parent's sibling bucket path in bucket-script,the DSL like this:

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "car_type": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "screenName",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "active_num": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "activeNum",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "active_count": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "activeNum"
              }
            },
            "result" : {
              "bucket_script": {
                "buckets_path": {
                  "count1" : "car_type>all_count",
                  "count2" : "active_count"
            },
                "script": "params.count2/params.count1"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "all_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "activeNum"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to use `all_count` in `result`, but es will throw Exception:

> No aggregation found for path [car_type>all_count]

Then,I change the place to use bucket_script,like this:

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "car_type": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "screenName",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "active_num": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "activeNum",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "active_count": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "activeNum"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "all_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "activeNum"
          }
        },
        "result" : {
          "bucket_script": {
             "buckets_path": {
                "count1" : "all_count",
                "count2" : "active_num>active_count"
              },
              "script": "params.count2/params.count1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but I get another Exception:

> buckets_path must reference either a number value or a single value numeric metric aggregation, got: java.lang.Object[]

I have found the official website page, but I get nothing.
How can I use this bucket_path?

Answer (score 0):

Using the following method can resolve some problems:

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "car_type": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "screenName",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "active_num": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
            "activeNum": "1"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "active_count": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "activeNum"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "all_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "activeNum"
          }
        },
        "result" : {
          "bucket_script": {
             "buckets_path": {
                "count1" : "all_count",
                "count2" : "active_num>active_count"
              },
              "script": "params.count2/params.count1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But there still has some problems,this method can only get one value's result,can not get every value of this field.
So, who has any other ideas?